# Could I convert a student visa to a job visa after graduation in Germany?

Tags: germany, student-visa

After an Indian national finishes their bachelors in Germany, can they convert their study visa into a work visa?

Comment: What has your own research revealed on this topic? A quick internet search will throw up a raft of information

Comment: are you sure? I couldn't find about this @Traveller

Comment: Try eg https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/study-training/studies-in-germany/prospects-after, https://www.upgradabroad.com/articles/germany-post-study-work-visa/